# Finding the tangential electric field from an offset off of a conductor

Tags: electrostatics

If we have a perfect conductor with a surface charge, there must be no tangential electric field at its boundary. However, what about at a differential distance normal to the surface? If we know the electric field at the surface across an arc length, $E_{surf} = E_n(s)$, my intuition would say that the tangential electric field at a differential offset would be $E_t(s) \sim \frac{dE_n(s)}{ds}$, but then I'm missing something because of the units don't match.